# File not found when installing gulp on Mac

Tags: macos, npm, gulp

I'm trying to install gulp, once again in my Mac but I'm not able to do it. I installed it before and it worked fine. I uninstalled using this:

```
npm uninstall gulp
```

But now when I try to install it again I got a lot of this kind of warnings with different modules

```
WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-6a1ce00e/node_modules/string_decoder/lib'
WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/es5-ext-802ca696/test/string/#/code-point-at'
WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-6a1ce00e/node_modules/string-width'
WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/es5-ext-802ca696/test/string/#/contains'
```

and Finally an error

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/atob/bin/atob.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/atob/bin/atob.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

What am I suppose to do?

Comment: How did you install it?